# How to put a newline in a long equation automatically

Tags: equations, line-breaking

How to format lines automatically in latex?

I wrote:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Lambda^{'}(pq-2)=4p^4q^4 - 4p^4q^3 - 4p^3q^4 - 2p^3q^3 + 4p^3q^2 + 4p^2q^3 -\\4(6pq - p - q - 5)(pq - 2)^3 + 5(pq - 2)^4 - 12p^2q^2 +3(13p^2q^2 - 5p^2q - 5pq^2 - 18pq + p + q + 10)(pq - 2)^2 +\\
10p^2q + 10pq^2 - 2(12p^3q^3 - 8p^3q^2 - 8p^2q^3 - 17p^2q^2
\\+ 5p^2q + 5pq^2 + 12pq + 6p + 6q - 8)(pq - 2) + 4pq - 4p -4q - 8
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I tried experimenting by putting `\\` to get a newline.
But the equation is not fitting in my page.
Its going outside of page.

Does there exist any command so that texmaker can automatically put the equation within the page?

Comment: Off topic: don't use `\Lambda^{'}` but simply `\Lambda'`.

Comment: I'm almost sure that *automatic* is not possible. You have to adjust by hand, inserting another new line, for example, at `\\ 12p^2q^2`.

Comment: @Sigur; thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

For automatic breaking of long output from computer algebra and similar systems it often helps to use inline math. As you want an equation number I wrapped that in a `\parbox` and `equation` here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\Lambda'(pq-2)=\parbox[t]{.75\textwidth}{$\displaystyle
4p^4q^4 - 4p^4q^3 - 4p^3q^4 - 2p^3q^3 + 4p^3q^2 + 4p^2q^3 -
4(6pq - p - q - 5)(pq - 2)^3 + 5(pq - 2)^4 - 12p^2q^2 +3(13p^2q^2 -
5p^2q - 5pq^2 - 18pq + p + q + 10)(pq - 2)^2 +
10p^2q + 10pq^2 - 2(12p^3q^3 - 8p^3q^2 - 8p^2q^3 - 17p^2q^2
+ 5p^2q + 5pq^2 + 12pq + 6p + 6q - 8)(pq - 2) + 4pq - 4p -4q - 8
$}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are superb!!, thanks a lot

Comment: One question sir, How can i go to a new line in this environment

Comment: Suppose I want to write $\implies $ in the new line, how can i go to a new line